# Multiple Response Regression in Spark MLLib

Tags: regression, machine-learning, random-forest, spark-mllib

I am trying to do a regression using RandomForests in Spark ML where I have several input variables and would like to predict several responses.

Training data would look like

```
X = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5]]
Y = [[5,6,7],[6,7,8]]
```

I am not very familiar with the LabeledPoint input format. How would I describe this problem? Is this possible in the current MLLib implementation?

Comment: We may not be able to address the software aspects, but the ML aspects we might. Can you say more about your response data? Do you have 2 continuous variables?

Comment: If you are willing to describe more you input data,I might be able to help you with Spark.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [RandomForestRegressor](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forest-regression) from the new Spark ML library (as opposed to MLlib which will be gradually phased out). For that you need to convert your data into a Spark dataframe:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
...     (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0)),
...     (0.0, Vectors.sparse(1, [], []))], ["label", "features"])
```

Alternatively, you can read-in and process the data from a csv file:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('./data/titanic.csv')
```

Once the data is loaded into the dataframe, you want to make sure that it contains numeric types (as opposed to strings) in order to run the regression. If you have multiple features, you would need to group them using VectorAssembler into a single features vector. Once that is done, you are ready to instantiate Random Forest Regressor and fit the model:

```
rf = RandomForestRegressor(numTrees=100, maxDepth=6, labelCol="label", featuresCol="features", seed=0)
model = rf.fit(trainingData)
```

For additional information have a look at the [regression example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/ml/random_forest_regressor_example.py) and [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html).